# How to solve NullPointerException at mailSender when using some organization as a host

Tags: spring, email, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send emails using an organisation mailSender.

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/forgetPassword", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes={"application/json"})
     public @ResponseBody User forgetPassword(@RequestBody User user) throws Exception { 

        user=userService.forgetPassword(user, newPassword);
        if(user !=null)
        {
            SendEmail callsendEmail = new SendEmail();
            callsendEmail.emailSender(user);
            return user;
        }
        else
        {
            return user;
        }
    }
```

**SendEmail**

```
public class SendEmail {

    private JavaMailSender mailSender;
    private VelocityEngine velocityEngine;
    private SimpleMailMessage templateMessage;

    public void emailSender(final User user) throws Exception {

        MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);

        message.setFrom(templateMessage.getFrom());
        message.setTo(user.getEmail());
        message.setSubject(templateMessage.getSubject());

        Map<String, User> model = new HashMap<String, User>();
        model.put("user", user);

        /*String text = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, "org/utility/mailTemplate.vm", model);
        message.setText(text, true);*/

        if (mailSender != null) {
            mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
        }
    }

    public void setVelocityEngine(VelocityEngine velocityEngine) {
        this.velocityEngine = velocityEngine;
    }

    public JavaMailSender getMailSender() {
        return mailSender;
    }

    public void setMailSender(JavaMailSender mailSender) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
    }

    public SimpleMailMessage getTemplateMessage() {
        return templateMessage;
    }

    public void setTemplateMessage(SimpleMailMessage templateMessage) {
        this.templateMessage = templateMessage;
    }
}
```

**Configuration**

```
<bean id="emailSender" class="org.utility.SendEmail">
    <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" /> 
    <property name="velocityEngine" ref="velocityEngine" /> 
    <property name="templateMessage" ref="templateMessage" /> 
  </bean>

  <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="10.6.12.229" /> 
    <property name="port" value="25" /> 
  </bean>
  <bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
    <property name="velocityProperties">
        <value>resource.loader=class class.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader</value> 
    </property>
  </bean>
  <bean id="templateMessage" class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">
    <property name="from" value="noreply@scrumtracker.com" /> 
    <property name="subject" value="Scrum Tracker Login Details" /> 
  </bean>
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/OLPV] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.utility.SendEmail.emailSender(SendEmail.java:24)
    at org.controller.UserController.forgetPassword(UserController.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:163)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:556)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:401)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:242)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:267)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:245)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:260)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm getting nullpointer exception on running the above code. Data is passing to the SendEmail class from Controller. Any idea on this?

Comment: An exception stack trace would help a little

Comment: Ok it's line 24 in your own class, that clears some things up. Now which line is line 24? Assuming that you have package & imports in the first X lines...

Comment: Line No 24 is - MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();

Comment: well it looks like the `mailSender` object is `NULL`, which makes sense because you only instantiate the `SendEmail` class and don't set any properties before using it `SendEmail callsendEmail = new SendEmail(); callsendEmail.emailSender(user);`

Comment: I see in debug mode that user object in SendEmail class is having data like username, email id etc.

Comment: It's because you pass `user` as a parameter

Answer (score 1):

1. Set @autowired from calling class (Don't do New) to the mailSend class.
2. Write @Service in mailSend class.
3. Directly call the mailSend.Send() method from the calling class.

All prop will be set automatically. No null point exception.

Namaste !

Answer (score 0):

In your `Controller` class you don't need to instantiante the `SendEmail` like you do

```
SendEmail callsendEmail = new SendEmail();
```

But instead inject it as a spring bean

```
@Controller
class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private SendEmail callsendEmail;

    @RequestMapping(value="/forgetPassword", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes={"application/json"})
     public @ResponseBody User forgetPassword(@RequestBody User user) throws Exception { 

        user=userService.forgetPassword(user, newPassword);
        if(user !=null)
        {
            callsendEmail.emailSender(user);
            return user;
        }
        else
        {
            return user;
        }
    }

}
```

If your application context is not configured to autowire beans by annotations, then use a regular setter in the class

```
@Required
public void setSendEmail( SendEmail sendEmail ) {
     this.callsendEmail = sendEmail;
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this approach but the problem still exists. I don't know what's wrong.